# Schema validation of empty array for nested structure verification

Tags: karate

I am working on a POC with Karate framework (latest version 0.9.6) and I came across with the following:

```
 * match each response.bar contains { id:"#uuid ? _ != ''", name: "#notnull", foo: "#[] #object"}
```

I noticed that, when **foo** is an empty array, it does not fail the step.
Is it possible to add a **length** verification on the above step to fail if the array is empty?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation

```
* match each response.bar contains { id:"#uuid ? _ != ''", name: "#notnull", foo: "#[_ > 0] #object"}
```

Comment: Awesome. I missed that. Thank you!